# How to get content-type response header in emscripten wget2 functions?

Tags: wget, emscripten, asm.js

OnLoad I'm getting only the response buffer, how do I get response headers?

see wget2 API: http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/emscripten.h.html#c.emscripten_async_wget2_data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [source of emscripten_async_wget2_data](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/42fb486c53d627b203b77af6e5d0c088c0ad03ad/src/library_browser.js#L913), there are no calls to [getResponseHeader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#getResponseHeader()) or [getAllResponseHeaders](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#getAllResponseHeaders()), so I suspect you cannot get access to the headers using [emscripten_async_wget2_data](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/emscripten.h.html#c.emscripten_async_wget2_data).

My suggestion is to not use the Emscripten-supplied API for ajax, and roll-your-own using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) (or favourite higher-level library), and use the techniques at [Emscripten's Connecting C++ and Javascript pages](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/index.html) to call out from C++ to your own implementation.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I was thinking of the same.

Comment: me too. I was afraid that it was going to be the answer. More work to do :-(